# AWS RDS write performance on primary in multi AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am curious on the performance of writes (SQL UPDATE or DELETE) to AWS RDS DB (multi AZ) when snapshot or backup is in progress.

I understand the manual snapshots and backups are taken from secondary node in multi AZ, but any changes due to DDL has to be synchronously replicated. Wont the DDL performance be slow in this case.

I could not find any documentation on this topic. All I found that the IO to the EBS volume is not suspended in primary. Theoretically, I feel on the primary node reads will not be impacted, but writes can be slow or suspended.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the Multi-AZ Page

> Unlike Single-AZ deployments, I/O activity is not suspended on your primary during backup for Multi-AZ deployments for the MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, and PostgreSQL engines, because the backup is taken from the standby. However, note that you may still experience elevated latencies for a few minutes during backups for Multi-AZ deployments.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/